# como traer los registros y agrupar los repetido y tambien mostrar?

Tags: mysql, sql

este es mi BD en phpmyadmin

```
commercer_id | commerce_district|
1              abacay
2              abacay
3              ahuac
4              alto de la alianza
5              alto de la alianza
6              amarilis
```

este es mi consulta, pero me traer todos los registros repetidos y con distinct igual, quisiera hacer la consulta que me traigas todos los registros pero que agrupe los repetidos y solo me traiga solo uno de los repetidos mas lo que no estan repetidos. soy nuevo en BD

```
SELECT 
commerce_district, commerce_id FROM commerc 
ORDER BY commerc.commerce_distric ASC
```

Comment: si agregas un `group by commerce_district`

Comment: si. con el group by soluciona un pedazo... ahora tener dos id para cada distrito es algo que no deberia pasar. En tal caso, que ID queres obtener de los dos que tenes?

Comment: gracias  JackNavaRow

Comment: los de los ID lo pude solucionar colocandole UNIQUE para que no se repitan @gbianchi

Comment: ese es el error principal , si son claves principales no deben repetirse

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la cláusula `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT commerce_district, COUNT(commercer_id) AS [assigned_id]
FROM commerc
GROUP BY commerce_district
ORDER BY COUNT(commercer_id) ASC
```

Como en tu caso algunos distritos tienen asignado más de un `id` lo que debes hacer es contar los `id`, agrupando por distrito, y de este modo te muestra lo que necesitas.

```
commerce_district | assigned_id |
ahuac               1
amarilis            1
abacay              2
alto de la alianza  2
```